# What is this warning?

Tags: footnotes, classicthesis, footmisc

```
    Using package "footmisc" with option "flushmargin" 
for footnote setup (not 100\% the same as with KOMA)
```

What does that mean? How can I remove this warning?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: I have added a minimal example.

Comment: The `classicthesis` package *can* be used with `article`, but the result might be different than with `scrartcl`; this is one of the possibilities. No big deal, I believe.

Comment: @Thankyou I believe you can ignore this warning. It just seems to be an information rather than a real warning.

Comment: The current version is `classicthesis 2012/08/12 v4.1`.  As far as I know is `classicthesis` not longer maintained, and there had been some changes in KOMA-Script and other packages, used by `classicthesis`.  That's the reason you get more and more warnings. Your mentioned warning is a notice, that the used packages in `classicthesis` deactivates special functionality of KOMA-Script. It is only a notice.  You will get more warnings if you change your MWE to `scrartcl` (KOMA-Script).

Answer (score 2):

The author of `classicthesis` (package/template) did so many things that are not recommended with use of a KOMA class (the template uses one). The package simply does not care which class is loaded and presumes that things are done like done in the template.

There are so many many places where the package needs some awareness of its surroundings and only (afair) when it comes to footnotes, is tested if a command provided by KOMA is defined. If not, a non-KOMA class is assumed and an extra helper package is loaded.

Maybe someone should drop a note to the author, that that very functionality that is tested is provided by package `scrextend`, which was designed wo work with non-KOMA classes.

The newest version of the template fixes some minor issues, but leaves the big ones untouched (too many users would be affected).